# download Facebook profile picture URL from graph API

Tags: facebook, api

I am able to access my user image from FB with graph api

how can i get  http://facebook.com/pic.jpg . the json return me pic URL but
 .type is missing in Url.
any suggestions for getting the full path to my image with that .jpg extension from graph api or with the user id, thank you.

Comment: You really should clarify how you're trying to do it. Your question as it stands is very vague.

Comment: sorry i m not good in english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use get header to take the original url which have the type of pic

```
$URL='FB GRAPH API URL';
$headers = get_headers($URL, 1); // make link request and wait for redirection
    if(isset($headers['Location'])) {
      $URL = $headers['Location']; // this gets the new url with type
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

you can get the display pic of any user using the following URL :

https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/picture?width=90&height=90

in the above URL, just replace, USER_ID with the user id that you received in the JSON.

Also, you can modify the height and width which i have set to 90.